# Go gin session after redirecting

Tags: go, go-gin

Session is working fine in the same handler, but when redirecting from route to other one, session is not working

also i used session in routing class like this

```
store := cookie.NewStore([]byte("secret"))
router.Use(sessions.Sessions("sessions", store))
```

Here is the controller code

```
func (controller *TestController) Register(c *gin.Context) {
    var session = sessions.Default(c)

    session.AddFlash(models.ErrorMsg{Field: "name", Message: "invalid input"}, "errors")
    session.Save()

    c.Redirect(http.StatusMovedPermanently, "/register")
    return
}

func (controller *TestController) HandleRegister(c *gin.Context) {
    var session = sessions.Default(c)

    errors := session.Flashes("errors")

    c.JSON(200, gin.H{
        "errors": errors,
    })
}
```

Comment: Its probably not a good idea to do what you are doing, that way. If `HandleRegister` relies on `Register` adding something to the session,  but `Register` redirects permanently, the browser will remember this redirect forever (until its cache is hard purged). So the user will never again hit that `Register` route. If the session expires at some point or cookies are cleared, you got a problem.

Comment: So what is the best practice to solve this
returning view template if there is an error ?

Comment: I don't really get what you code is doing tbh. I also don't see a view template used somewhere. I am also not sure where you redirect to since you don't show how you register your routes. I just wanted to point out that this permanent redirect might be problematic, if register redirects to handleRegister. I cannot tell if that's actually the case because, again, you don't show under what path these handlers are served.

Comment: It just two routes
register method[GET] hander [Register]
register method[POST] handler [HandleRegister]

So the route GET register will show template for user just show views and render if there is any error

POST register will do validation from inputs that will come from register template and if there is any error, it will redirect to GET register with flash messages

Comment: Can you update your answer and show more code please? Afaik you cannot redirect a post to a get method. It will always stay a post request. That's just how http works. And permanent redirect tells the browser to remember where it got redirected to and go there right away next time.

Comment: Or even better, create a minimal reproducable example.